# How do I terminate my subprocesses in Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, subprocess

I have two subprocesses as I showed below

```
cmd1='arecord -d 0 -f cd -t wav test.wav'
cmd2='raspivid -o video.h264 -fps 25 -t 0'

pro1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, shell=True)
pro2 = subprocess.Popen(cmd2, shell=True)
```

I want to record audio and video at the same time with raspberry pi. From now on I can start both programs but I cannot stop these programs. Can anybody help me?

Or any idea for doing  by simple way this process?

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> **Popen.terminate()** Stop the child. On Posix OSs the method sends
>   SIGTERM to the child. On Windows the Win32 API function
>   TerminateProcess() is called to stop the child.
>
> New in version 2.6.
>
> **Popen.kill()** Kills the child. On Posix OSs the function sends SIGKILL
>   to the child. On Windows kill() is an alias for terminate().

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [Python's subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) includes a description of `Popen.terminate()` and `Popen.kill()`.